# Recursive search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo collection that contains data sets with a pmID and a replyID, where the replyID can be null or a pmID. I'm trying to figure out, if I select by a pmID, how I can also get the PM where the pmID = replyID, and if that set's replyID isn't null, the object that matches that, etc.

```
{
    pmID: 1,
    replyID: null
},
{
    pmID: 2,
    replyID: null
},
{
    pmID: 3,
    replyID: 1
},
{
    pmID: 4,
    replyID: 3
}
```

So if I selected on pmID = 4, I also wanna get 3 and 1. I'm debating just doing a one by one select, but I'm hoping there's an easier answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure of your use case here, but from a glance I would personally model to store the "ancestors" in order with the object like so:

```js
{
    "pmId": 1,
    "replyIds": [ ]
},
{
    "pmId": 3,
    "replyIds": [ 1 ]
},    
{
    "pmId": 4,
    "replyIds": [ 3, 1 ]
}
```

In either that order or in reverse depending on how you implement the ancestor history.

The point being that when issuing a "reply" to an existing object, you should already have the data loaded that tells you if there are any existing replies. The new object then pushes the id of the the object it is being issued in reply to onto the the existing "replyIds" array when that new object is created:

```js
// data is "pmId": 3 object

data.replyIds.unshift( data.pmId );
data.pmId = getNewPmId(); // whatever

db.collection.insert(data);
```

It's a fairly simple pattern which obviates the need to "recursively walk" through queries on read requests, and also allows for simple writes.

Retrieving all ancestors is just a simple matter of passing the array of replies to [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```js
var data = db.collection.findOne({ "pmId": 4 });

db.collection.find({ "pmId": { "$in": data.replyIds } })
```

Comment: That's a great point, thanks! I'll take a look, that may be my solution. That being said, what is getNewPmId() in your solution? A function I'm guessing? I read that selecting objects in a function doesn't go through the index; it was confusing, and I'm worried I misunderstood what it was saying. I haven't really done anything with functions yet.

Comment: @RhoVisions Not really sure what a "pmId" is to you and I just take it as being a "example", so just "some method" to get a unique identifier. Of course if you just use an `ObjectId` and "pmId" is really the primary `_id` key then there would be no need for custom logic to get a "new unique id".

Comment: I'm a MySQL guy making the move to learn/use Mongo, so I still end up using some SQL conventions. pmID is a sequential id in addition to the mongo generated _id. I'd use just the mongo generated one, but when trying to do URL friendly stuff, a short, unique ID is much easier.

Comment: There is a section in the manual [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) that covers the concepts. My point here is that arrays are often the solution to "joins" and "ancestor trees" and can be implemented in a simple say.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Neil's suggestion to use ancestor arrays, if you're modelling conversations you can group together conversations with a `conversation_id` and recall all messages connected to a given one by `conversation_id`:

```
{
    "pmId": 1,
    "conversationId" : 0
},
{
    "pmId": 3,
    "conversationId" : 0
},    
{
    "pmId": 4,
    "conversationId" : 0
}

> var pm = db.test.findOne({ "pmId" : 3 })
> db.test.find({ "conversationId" : pm.conversationId })
```

Comment: I was debating the conversation ID, but it doesn't quite work, because a conversation can diverge, meaning they'd share ancestors but not all the same.